# Plot data according to the date recorded

Tags: python, file, matplotlib

I have the following code that it takes a list of files. Using their data it plots a pie chart and extracts the mean value and percentiles for each file specifically.

The file however, might contain recorded data from several days. (The file has on the left column the date and on the right the values recorded.) Now I have to do the same thing as before, but instead of plotting and getting the mean value from each whole file, I need to plot the pie chart and get the mean value for each date recorded in the file.

```
import dateutil.parser
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import pandas as pd

selection = input('Press all ')
counter=0
files1 = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\And\Documents\testing *.csv')
d2={}
for sfile in files1:
    if selection == 'all':
        x=[]
        y=[]
        z=[]
        xtime=0
        ytime=0
        ztime=0
        data_file = np.genfromtxt(sfile, delimiter=',', usecols=range(2),unpack=True,skip_header=10,dtype='U')
        tdelta=dateutil.parser.parse(data_file[0][1][11:])-dateutil.parser.parse(data_file[0][0][11:])
        tseconds=tdelta.total_seconds()
        for i in data_file[1]:
            if i != 0:
                if float(i) >= 55:
                    x.append(float(i))
                    xtime+=tseconds
                elif float(i)>40 and float(i)<55:
                    y.append(float(i))
                    ytime+=tseconds
                else:
                    z.append(float(i))
                    ztime+=tseconds
        labels = ["upper", "middle", "lower"]
        sizes=[xtime,ytime,ztime]
        legends=[xtime,ytime,ztime]
        colors=["blue","orange","yellow"]
        plt.pie(sizes, explode=(0.1,0,0), labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=140)
        plt.legend(legends, loc='best')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.show()
        plt.savefig("test{filename}.png".format(filename=counter))
        plt.clf()
        xarray=np.asarray(x)
        yarray=np.asarray(y)
        zarray=np.asarray(z)
        totalarray=np.append(zarray,np.append(xarray,yarray))
        counter+=1

        EQ=np.mean(totalarray)
        P15, P50, P85 = np.percentile(totalarray, 15), np.percentile(totalarray, 50), np.percentile(totalarray, 85)
        d2[sfile[36:]]=[f'{P15:.2f}',f'{P50:.2f}',f'{P85:.2f}', f'{EQ:.2f}']
table1 = pd.DataFrame(d2,index=['P15', 'P50', 'P85', 'EQ'])
table= table1.T
```

[The image shows a portion of the data in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwBKZ.png)

I am having trouble writing a code that is able to create a list of pie charts according to the different dates that the files contain, and not plotting one pie chart for the whole file. At the end I would like to have a table with the mean value for each date. Any help how to modify the code to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: The actual data would be a lot more useful than a picture of the data.

Comment: It might be easier to manipulate the data if you first import this into a pandas dataframe.
`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')` This can then be manipulated to extract the required data (i.e. filter by date) such as `data_data = df[df['date_column']=='01/01/2000']`.
You could then plot the data from this filtered dataset.

Comment: I have used a dictionary and I can now sort the dates with their data and use the DataFrame:
        for i,p in zip(data_file[0],data_file[1]):
            if i[:10] in d1:
                d1[i[:10]].append(p)
            else:
                d1[i[:10]]=[p]
                d3[i[:10]]=tseconds
This did the trick for me :)